# AtmelStudio7: MPLABCOMM_INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: atmelstudio

beginner question ...

Hi,

when I try to run the application (even if there is only an empty loop, compile/build are ok) i get the following error:

Unable to connect, Failed to open: MPLABCOMM_INVALID_HANDLE

Same thing this morning on another computer worked without problems.

Any ideas about the problem?

Hardware:
There is a atxmega128a1- based minicomputer with some buttons, display, clock ...
On the programmer is written: JTAGICE mkII

Software:
I use Win7 Professional (both times).
At home I installed Atmel Studio 7, at the other computer was installed AS 6.2 (this is the only difference I recognize)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by restarting Atmel Studio 7.